# How to copy layouts from one dxf to another dxf?

Tags: python, dxf, ezdxf

I have a dxf file file1.dxf with layouts ( layout F11, layout F12, layout F13)
I have another dxf file file2.dxf with layouts (layout F21, layout F22)
I want to copy the layouts from file1 to file2
How do I do that using ezdxf?
For now I copy them manually by opening the file2 on CAD and import the file1 layers by "clicking on *From Template* "
but copying too many layouts is tiresome.

Comment: I have not used ezdxf but it looks like the Layouts manager is documented: https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/layouts/ So I would expect you can extract the needed layouts into objects and then add them to the other database. But I can't tell you how.

Comment: There are different type sof layouts ofcourse. Like the paper space layouts: https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/layouts/layouts.html#paperspace